# LightDM login screen configuration

Tags: login, lightdm, login-screen, debian

I'm using Debian Stretch and my LoginScreen looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdjql.png). I wonder if it is possible to make it look like the [ubuntu version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDczO.png)? Especially I'd like to have the graphical user selector instead of a login box where I still have to retype the username at every login...

I experimented with the greeter user option in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` but without any success. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: I'm sorry, but we only support Ubuntu flavors here.

Comment: @heynnema -- Ubuntu Mate desktop has the same settings. or really any flavor using LightDM, so there is value to the post and answer.

Comment: @ravery Debian Stretch isn't supported here.

Comment: Ok I'll fix his question to make it fit here

Comment: @ravery that's overstepping what you should be doing. 4 users voted to close this question because it was off topic. You invalidated their reviews, and stepped on their toes (again). You should have just voted the same.

Comment: @this question is about LightDM and LightDM Greeter, ubuntu uses this DM and the answer given is the same regardless of distro

Comment: This is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17295/needlessly-closed-a-question). @heynnema You may want to post there. From the perspective of an outsider (to this specific discussion), what you are saying about stepping on the toes of reviewers doesn't make much sense. If a review or edit is wrong, it's wrong, but later reviewers have no obligation to agree with earlier reviewers.

Comment: @EliahKagan thanks for the heads up! I'll go and drop my 2 cents worth. The "stepping on toes" referred to the fact that 4 reviewers had VTC, and ravery went and edited the question, thereby (trying) to change the basis why the 4 VTC's were cast. ravery should have just VTC. Of course I agree that "later reviewers have no obligation to agree with earlier reviewers".

Answer (score 1):

/usr/share/lightdm is where the debian config files are. Lightdmgreeter.conf is the file for the greeter.
there is also `lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings` available in the repo.

add/change to `greeter-hide-users=false` in the file /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf  to get a user list. LightDM automatically rememer last user to log in.

If you don't want to type your password every time, you have to enable autologin.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I installed the package which gives me some configuration possibilities. But what setting do I have to change to switch to the user selection menu? I would like to have a list of users displayed where I only have to select one name and enter the password. Currently, I don't have a user list and have to enter the name - That is my problem.

Comment: add/change to  `greeter-hide-users=false` in the file /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf

Answer (score 1):

the greeter you use is gdm, original ubuntu use lightdm3, so just install it and configure it. 
first 'apt-get install lightdm3 ' then,  run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm3` choose lightdm3. reboot, you will go to the ubuntu greeter(login screen)

Comment: he is using LightDM

Comment: Yes, I am. But the name of the package is not lightdm3. It is only lightdm. I have still the same style of the login screen, but now the loginname is displayed in a selection box. I think that there is now possibility to switch to the fancy ubuntu design?

Comment: do you means that the background is not the same with ubuntu version?

Comment: No, not especially the background. As you can see in the posted images, the style is different. While my ldm has a grey centered login box, the Ubuntu version displays a list of users which seems to be directly displayed on the background

Comment: I am not sure if the following solution woks. ubuntu use unity as the desktop environment based on gnome,  you can just install the unity to have a try, in original ubuntu, I remember the greeter is lightdm3. if you not custom to unity, just reinstall ubuntu-gnome with lightdm3 seletected(during the installing process you have to choose lightdm or gdm)

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I will leave it as it is now. I did not want to start a huge on-/off-topic discussion. Likely, there is no solution for my question.